# Orderless in completion-styles

Tags: completion, completion-styles

Have seen that `completion-styles` now includes `orderless`.  Does this mean that there is no need to install `orderless` in emacs, or do I still have to install it?

This is from looking at the code where `completion-styles-alist` has value

```
((orderless orderless-try-completion orderless-all-completions "Completion of multiple components, in any order.")
```

Comment: Where have you seen that `completion-styles` includes `orderless`?

Comment: Not in the [Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Completion-Styles.html) as of Nov 2022.

Comment: Looked at the code.  `completion-styles-alist` has `Value:
((orderless orderless-try-completion orderless-all-completions "Completion of multiple components, in any order.")`.

Comment: Starting from `emacs -Q`? Also, are you using some kind of Emacs distribution/starter-kit?

Comment: Could have been introduced by `orderless` perhaps.  I see it is not actual code then, just a list being filled up.  You are right the entry for `orderless` in not in the `alist` when using `emacs -Q`.

Comment: Using something like Doom Emacs or Spacemacs, or even a Linux distribution that packages up orderless for you, could do this. You won't see orderless in `completion-styles-alist` if you use vanilla Emacs and just install the orderless package. That is why the orderless REAME shows how to add it yourself: https://github.com/oantolin/orderless.  If you want to debug this, you could use https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Debugging.html to add code to your init file that will cause Emacs to break into the debugger when `completion-style-alist` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real reference to `orderless` for the completion style in GNU Emacs as of even the tip of the `master` branch in the Git repository (as of Nov. 14, 2022).  The default `completion-styles` reads like this:

```elisp
(defcustom completion-styles
  ;; First, use `basic' because prefix completion has been the standard
  ;; for "ever" and works well in most cases, so using it first
  ;; ensures that we obey previous behavior in most cases.
  '(basic
    ;; Then use `partial-completion' because it has proven to
    ;; be a very convenient extension.
    partial-completion
    ;; Finally use `emacs22' so as to maintain (in many/most cases)
    ;; the previous behavior that when completing "foobar" with point
    ;; between "foo" and "bar" the completion try to complete "foo"
    ;; and simply add "bar" to the end of the result.
    emacs22)
  "List of completion styles to use.
The available styles are listed in `completion-styles-alist'.

Note that `completion-category-overrides' may override these
styles for specific categories, such as files, buffers, etc.

Note that Tramp host name completion (e.g., \"/ssh:ho<TAB>\")
currently doesn't work if this list doesn't contain at least one
of `basic', `emacs22' or `emacs21'."
  :type completion--styles-type
  :version "23.1")
```

In fact a simple search through the entire repository only briefly mentions it in a custom theme (`modus-themes`), in as much as the theme alters the appearnce of some `orderless` match faces (but does not *define* them):

```
doc/misc/modus-themes.org:Also refer to the documentation of the ~orderless~ package for its
doc/misc/modus-themes.org:+ orderless
etc/themes/modus-themes.el:Also refer to the documentation of the `orderless' package for
etc/themes/modus-themes.el:;;;;; orderless
etc/themes/modus-themes.el:    `(orderless-match-face-0 ((,class :inherit modus-themes-completion-match-0)))
etc/themes/modus-themes.el:    `(orderless-match-face-1 ((,class :inherit modus-themes-completion-match-1)))
etc/themes/modus-themes.el:    `(orderless-match-face-2 ((,class :inherit modus-themes-completion-match-2)))
etc/themes/modus-themes.el:    `(orderless-match-face-3 ((,class :inherit modus-themes-completion-match-3)))
```

So it is completely necessary to add your own `orderless` package into (GNU) Emacs, if you wish to use it, even on the latest released version, 28.2.  I suspect you may have a non-GNU Emacs with 'extras' installed, or perhaps some external package or initialization file has added this token to `completion-styles` for you.